# Where do air molecules move at the greatest speed in a sound wave?

Tags: waves, speed, vibrations

In my lecture notes it states that

> The movement of the particles is greatest were the gas is rarefied.

But I wold disagree. I would think that the speed of particles is exactly zero at the compressions and rarefaction and is maximum in between.

Could anyone explain if/where I am going wrong?

Comment: Sound waves at audible frequencies are mostly adiabatic.  What would you assume about temperatures in an adiabatic compression?

Comment: Look at it the other way around. That is, assume that at regular intervals there are speed maxima and minimal. Now where do you think the compression and rarefactions will be found?

Comment: @JMLCarter i don't think i have very good intuition about this; considering speed minima and maxima, I would think the maximum speed would be where the compressions are, on either side of the centre of the compression (with centre of compression not moving) certainly not at the rarefaction. Also, I just noticed that I am picturing standing ound waves as this whole lecture topic is about standing waves. Perhaps here my lecturer was simply giving an introduction to longitudinal waves in general?

Comment: Ah yes I think my difficulty has been that I have been considering the longitudinal standing waves. Now looking at http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/waves/wavemotion.html animation of travelling sound waves and http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/StandingWaves/StandingWaves.html of standing sound waves in a pipe, I see that the greatest speed in the standing wave case is indeed between compressions and rarefactions and for the travelling wave is at the rarefactons, as suggested by my lecturer. Intuitively, I also see how what my lecturer said must be the case. Considering each particle

Comment: as undergoing simple harmonic motion in the longituinal direction, the particle speed is greatest passing through the centre of oscillation, and the greatest particle speed also means that there will be the greatest distance between two successive points which have slightly different phases of SHM. Thus particle speed greatest at a rarefaction point for a travelling wave.